# How to remove default styles from react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I was making an app with react native and react-navigation. So what I did was I made a Login screen. Then I used react-navigation to create a native stack navigator and linked it to my Login screen. I successfully rendered the Login Screen but there seems to be some sort of default styling on the stack navigator(?). How do I remove or overwrite those styles so that the original styling of my screens come back? Images and Code below.

This is the stack navigator

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import SignUpScreen from '../screens/SignUpScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login" screenOptions={{ header: () => null }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignUpScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AuthStack;
```

When I only render the LoginScreen it looks like this

[image: Only using LoginScreen]

When I use AuthStack it looks like this
[image: After using AuthStack]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have read the docs nicely it was there in the NativeStackNavigator options.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import SignUpScreen from '../screens/SignUpScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          header: () => null,
          contentStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white' },
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignUpScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AuthStack;
```

Answer (score 1):

To do your own style do this

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from "@reactnavigation/native";

 const MyTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
       ...DefaultTheme.colors,
       background: Color.red,
      },
    };
```

Then do this

```
<NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="startscreen" headerMode="none"  >
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

More information here (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/)